# two threads cannot share data in python

Tags: python-multithreading

I am new to multithread programming, I put my media_player and server in two threads, the server is to receive the data which is the operation to media_player from another client program. But the valueof "operation" i get from server isn't updata to my main thread, so the output of operation in media_player is always none, I hope it will change as the server receives data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`global operation` shall be added into the function, otherwise it would just make a local copy of it and start from here.